# Grinding sound when shifting up into 3rd gear from 2nd

Tags: clutch, grinding

just a quick question on the clutch I have on a vw polo.
The car makes a short grind sound when shifting up into 3rd gear from second. 
It doesn't make this sound if it is shifted down into 3rd from any gear.

This only started yesterday.

Comment: Check that your hydraulic clutch fluid is full. Other than that, it sounds like your synchronizers might be going out. Does rev-matching before shifting into gear make a difference?

Comment: I have had sporadic griding when shifting from 1st to 2nd gear. Turned out to be a worn clutch system. Replaced the clutch kit and all was oke. With that I replaced by master cylinder as well since it was a bit worn. hope it helps